# Python : UI Image Wipe, compare two images

Tags: python, image, maya

I wanted to know if anyone knew where to start in terms of recreating this sort of functionality? 
http://www.learningnuke.com/wp-content/uploads/nukewipepreview.png

In the picture you can drag the centre line to reveal Image A or Image B or parts of each, interactively.

I want to be able to wipe/reveal across two images, maybe it's possible doing some sort of  interactive crop of sorts. 
Wanting to add this feature to a window in Maya, so maybe with QT, but not essential.

Just some pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that this is possible via Qt/PyQt in maya. You can create a dialog that displays QPixmaps with some form of mouse interaction to control their display. I would forget about trying to extend the actual Render View as this would be a pain in the ass.

Just focus on a Qt solution. Unfortunately beyond this, I'm not sure what more I can offer unless you  have a specific question about its implementation.

I would probably stack the QPixmaps on top of each other inside of custom QLabel widgets. The QLabel would have a custom mousepress/move event that would resize maybe the right edge to simulate the wipe effect, and reveal the one stacked underneath.

Also, it does resemble the functionality of a QSplitter so that might also work, with an image on each side of the layout and a custom style to the split bar.

Comment: awesome! Yeah you understood my intentions, I initially wanted to put some plots for the render window, but then saw modo 601 renderView and immediately got jealous.

So, yeah i plan on doing the renderView in QT, I'll give your suggestion a go then I'll probably come back for help. My usage of QT is only basic UI's at the moment using the designer, can you use QSplitter there?

Comment: Yes Designer does let you create a splitter between two widgets. Though to get the functionality you need you will ultimately need to get your hands dirty with some custom widgetry

Comment: thank you very much jdi! Extremely prompt replies. HAH...hey Justin, just realised it was you. You answered my other question on python inside maya. lol. thanks man

Comment: Yeah that worked nicely, stacking the two images, but now my knowledge of QT is very limited.
What project would I need to create in QT to be able to create custom mouse events? I have only used the designer form and that only allows you to edit the ui/xml file. 
Is that right? Would I edit that, or can I do something in python or would it be c++ ?

Comment: The designer is mostly limites to doing the layout. The initial project you select is just a visual starter. All of the wiring and whatnot is accomplished in code. You can do it in either c++, or in python if you have installed pyqt for maya

Comment: excellent. that should be enough for me now. Thanks heaps justin.